# How do I turn a folder into a .jar file?

Tags: macos, java

I currently have modified a program that is a `.jar` file. I had unarchived it and turned the `.jar` file into a folder so that I could edit it. Now all I need to do is change the folder back into a `.jar` file so that it is not accessible like a folder. How would I do this?

Comment: What did you edit - the parts of a jar are compiled code and not manually editable

Comment: Wrong. Might also be assets.

Comment: @Mark you could also supply your own compiled code. I assume the OP is talking about Minecraft.

Answer (score 7):

Jar files are almost zip files in most cases, but I would use the `jar cf` command for best results.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

You could just use OS X compression and [then rename the zip file as .jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220680/how-do-i-convert-the-src-zip-file-to-jar-file) - but then you might not have a correct manifest file. It's hard to tell without the exact files in hand.

Comment: What happens if you just rename it xxxxx.jar ? I've seen ML do some amazing file recognitions ...

Comment: You add four characters to the folder name. It's still a folder and not a zipped folder stored as one file. The amazing things are when OS X launch services send a renamed file to a different path and class of files to open it. Java might be smart enough to run on a jar named folder uncompressed, but you don't have a jar file instead of a folder (no matter what it's named).

Comment: @bmike Java can use a directory rather than a jar file - if the classpath and directory have the correct values - but this should be covered in Java tutorials

Comment: @Mark Thanks for the comments here and on the question. My java-fu is weak due to atrophy. I'm probably more dangerous than knowledgable at this point.

Answer (score -4):

umm i tried several videos and they all said rename the file

Comment: I suppose if your app doesn't care that nothing is compressed and the .jar folder loads this is a nice solution, but I think the asker wants to re-achive the jar since they went to the trouble to explain it was unarchived first.

Comment: -1, this will not generate a manifest.